# Putting checkboxes below an AChartEngine graph

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, achartengine, android-checkbox

I would like to include some checkboxes below the graph, but have no idea how to do so. As it stands, the graph is sortav taking over the whole screen, so I suppose I should start by making it smaller, which I also don't know how to do.
This is what it currently looks like when I try to show the checkboxes:

[image]

Also, here is my current xml code for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ViewGraphActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View which lines:" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distance" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:text="Time" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Velocity" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:text="Calories" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `checkbox_container`:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true" => android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am assuming it worked because the check boxes aren't on the chart anymore, however they disappeared and I still have no idea how to make the chart a bit smaller to see if I can see the check boxes... =/

Comment: @theJuls Well that's rather easy too, you just set `android:layout_above="@+id/checkbox_container"` in your 'android:id="@+id/chart_container"' element.

Comment: Thanks it worked! It turns out I was doing the opposite: putting android:layout_belo="@+id/chart_container" on the checkbox_container. Not sure why this one works over ther other. No matter though, it works just fine now :)

Comment: It's possibly because the behavior of `wrap_content` for charts made them take up all the available space, which forced checkboxes off the screen. Since checkboxes have rather small, predictable height, you're now telling charts to make sure they consider whatever height checkboxes need, not vice versa, that's why it works.